# How to show task progress in android as loading spinner

Tags: android

i have working with a project based on Bluetooth home automation.which is worked perfectly.but i have a problem is that, when the user select a particular device from paired list,i cant able to give a progress bar to indicate the process is under progress.how to show a progress of a task in a loading spinner. i have a listview with paired devices.when the user click the device , it will show the progress dialog.and when the device is connected then it must be disappear.
pls give any solution

Comment: Have you tried `ProgessDialog.show()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)